# Convert column of serial dates (yyyy-mm-dd) to UK date format (Pythonic way)

Tags: python, date

I am trying to convert a date of the format yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy and readable by Excel. I have tried:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

But get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to convert the column to `datetime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Also - if the OP's using pandas' `to_excel` method, then it might even be reasonable to leave the value as a datetime in the DF for terms of convenient date handling and not reformat it as a string and just let Excel format it as per the user settings/locale when opened.